# dpkg reports gtk is installed, but make can't find it

Tags: dpkg, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to compile a non-commercial biological database system on an AMD64 ubuntu machine (running 14.04), and I can't get it to work yet.  The database relies on gtk+-2.0, but can't find it.  I did this:

```
% dpkg -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================

ii  libgtk-3-0:amd 3.10.8-0ubun amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface lib

ii  libgtk2.0-0:am 2.24.23-0ubu amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface lib
```

which seems to tell me that versions of both gtk+-2.0 and gtk+-3.0 are installed.  If I then try to make the installation, I get stuff like this:

```
gcc -g -Wall  -DACEDB4 `../w3rdparty/include-config  gtk+-2.0`  -I.. -I../wh -I../wstaden -DACEDB_GTK -DOPTERON -c -o aceversion.o aceversion.c
Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
```

I've been all over the web trying to find out where the gtk libraries are stored so I can set the environment variable, and no place suggested seems to be right.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you just have the *runtime* library packages: you need the *development* package(s) e.g. `libgtk2.0-dev` for gtk+-2.0

Comment: Beautiful, thank you.  The ubuntu software center doesn't seem to have these, so the best place would be gtk.org?

Comment: The software center only displays packages with an "appinfo" file. You can imagine those as Applications instead of Programs, meaning they ate targeted to the standard user, have a GUI etc. - Programs are development libraries etc. They are not installable via the software center. Install them via synaptic or apt-get as Julian Stirling wrote.

Answer (score 2):

You need the development packages, they should be available in 14.04 from the trusty main repository. Try running:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

Comment: Many thanks, everybody.  I did in fact get these to install as you suggested, and I appreciate the clarifications.